# Como mudar a data 2017-07-04 12:53:14 para Dia/Mes/Ano com PHP

Tags: php

Como mudar a data 2017-07-04 12:53:14  para Dia/Mes/Ano e continuar o horario normal com PHP, ele esta vindo assim "2017-07-04 12:53:14" do banco de dados

Quero que fique 04/07/2017 12:53:14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode formatar assim

```
date_format(date_create("2017-07-04 12:53:14"), "d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

Comment: Vlw deu certo :D